# Where in 'react' file can I find Component module?

Tags: reactjs

Trying to find source code for React.Component, ReactDOM.render etc. Since  Component are built-in modules that can be imported using import { Component } from 'react'.I looked into facebook/react GitHub source code but unable to locate it. I was able to find ReactBaseClasses.js which seems to be the one for how Component is defined for React. Just making sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn how to navigate code that you didn't wrote. Easiest way would be to clone repository,  open it in your preferred code editor,  and navigate starting from the entry point via `ctrl+click` (may vary depending on editor) on symbols that you are interested in.

For your precise question - Component is indeed defined in ReacatBaseClasses.js.